# Android app for third party that can share on Facebook

Tags: android, facebook

I'm developing (actually it's done, only the Facebook and Hyves shares are missing) Android mobile app that should share image to Face and Hyves.

There are couple of problems that I do not understand, so I need (urgent) help.

My idea was to save user/pass on device, and to check during the input if these details are correct. Then I wanted to somehow use API's to share image on the wall, preferably without any additional apps created, just share photo like you would share it from gallery.

Now I'm reading Facebook Developers guide, and it advises to create facebook app with domanin / e-mail, but this is not my app and I do not have authority to create anything in the name of third party.

So, what is the proper way to share photo to Social Networks, without creating "apps" and getting apps ID and stuff.

It seems that I can't find that kind of info on FB Developers page, and I'm afraid how will I get proper information for hyves (Dutch social network, and I do not speek dutch).